# Extended Hückel method: what are the atomic orbital energies usually used?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I was checking out an extended Hückel (non-iterative) code, and realised that for s-block elements it would be impossible to simply use atomic ionisation energies as an approximation to the orbital potential energies (due to the p orbitals being empty). In this case, what values are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following reference:

> A. Herman, Modelling Simul. Mater. Sci. Eng. 2004, 12, 21.

It has $H_{vv}$ terms for different orbitals of all elements of the table.